# Dynamic folder list output with XML input

Tags: xml

Is there an easy way to create a folder structure output from an XML input. Below is a sample of the XML input I am trying to parse:

```
  <file name="tmpFile1" path="{{Base}}\folder1\V1\Samples\DotNet\C#\VS2005\tmpFolder1" />
  <file name="tmpFile2" path="{{Base}}\folder1\V2\Samples\DotNet\C#\VS2005\tmpFolder2" />
```

Hoping I can get an output like with Windows Folders (with Base=C:):

[alt text http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/9311/structure.jpg](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/9311/structure.jpg)

Any ideas here?

Comment: What languages are you using - how are you processing the document?

Comment: right now the XML document is being processed manually by me to create a folder structure with the files (it's quite taxing and very time consuming). I'm open to any language that would be easy, quick and lightweight to work with. FYI: I know a little about a lot of languages, but have no depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in...UI output? You might want to be more specific and supply what language you're working with.

If you're just interested in opening an explorer window, you could call explorer with particular arguments: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/02/07/command-line-switches-to-display-special-objects-or-folders-when-opening-windows-explorer/

In their example, calling %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /N,%WinDir%\System32,/Select,%WinDir%\System32\Ping.exe will open System32 in the left pane and focus on Ping.exe in the right pane.

If you mean constructing a file tree explorer in a particular language or UI framework, I'm afraid you'll have to actually specify which one you're working in. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

I'm open to suggestions for any coding language. This is an internal tool that I want to create to parse XML (from a file list of Perforce files) to create a tree structure for an InstallShield installer. The tool used to create the XML is in java (not my choice...but it works). 

Take it easy though, I'm not a developer by default. :)

Comment: I'd recommend you use C#, since it seems you're going to be interacting with Windows & its file systems. Are you creating the tree structure so that a user can select one item in the tree as a directory location, or something like that?

If so - you could probably just use a regular file browser dialog: http://www.kirupa.com/net/using_open_file_dialog_pg4.htm

If you really need a tree view, I would examine this piece of code for building a tree view: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Explorer_Tree.aspx